# how to write sql condition in jooq

Tags: sql, conditional-statements, inline, where-clause, jooq

i use jooq for data base manipulation.I want to write a select statement with custom where cause. Meaning conditions comes as map and i creating a where cause by iterating a map.data in the map change time to time. That's why i iterating the map and create where cause

```
Map =>{fromDate=>2014-05-10,toDate=>2014-06-10,userId=25,type=>STAFF}
```

then creating a where cause like below.

```
where (fromDate="2014-05-10" and toDate="2014-06-10" and userId=25 and type="STAFF")
```

So can i write a where cause inline.

Thank you
Amila

Comment: [For the record, this question was cross-posted on the jOOQ user group](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/jooq-user/Vp69hWJ3G1E/r7naq8DjBpkJ)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what you mean by creating a where clause "inline". But probably, the best solution is to write a utility function like this:

```java
public static Condition condition(Map<Field<?>, Object> map) {
    Condition result = DSL.trueCondition();

    for (Entry<Field<?>, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        result = result.and(((Field) entry.getKey()).eq(entry.getValue()));
    }

    return result;
}
```

You can then, "inline" that condition into your jOOQ statement:

```java
DSL.using(configuration)
   .select(...)
   .from(...)
   .where(condition(map))
   .fetch();
```